# Migration DevServer 14.1 VC11 to DevServer 16.1 VC14

Tags: easyphp

i had before EasyPhp Devserver 14.1 VC11 and now i pay and install Devserver 16.1 VC14.

When i open the dashboard and try to start the server... nothing... No error message, no warning, anything...

I have windows 10 with all the VC i need... When i look in the console (Google Chrome) i can see 2 error 404

GET http://127.0.0.1:1111/library/bootstrap/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js

GET http://127.0.0.1:1111/library/bootstrap/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js

Someone can help me please? I have to uninstall and clean in "regedit" or something?

Comment: If you paid for the upgrade, why are you not asking the product support for help with your installation problems?

Comment: I have no answer and they said "go to stackoverflow and github to post your question" lol

Comment: Then contact them again and tell them you paid for it and it's not working, and you need them to help you get it to work.